# #Context error combining queries in SAP BO BI Platform 4.2

Tags: business-intelligence, business-objects

I am using BO BI Launch Pad version 14.2.4.2410.
I am encountering a context error when efforting to combine two queries, both of which reference our product table.

The first query looks like this:

```
SELECT 
C.Case_No, 
P.Product_Name 
FROM 
Case_table C, 
Product_table P 
WHERE 
C.Case_No = P.Case_No 
AND 
P.Product_Type = "Suspect"
```

The second query looks like this:

```
SELECT 
C.Case_No, 
P.Product_Name 
FROM 
Case_table C, 
Product_table P 
WHERE 
C.Case_No = P.Case_No 
AND 
P.Product_Type <> "Suspect"
```

The first query returns one row per case.  The second query can return zero-to-many rows per case.

I have created variables for the second query which allow the report to display a single row for each case with all of the non-suspect product names concatentated one after the other.

I have merged C.Case_No from the two queries.

When I effort to add a column for the concatenated non-suspect product variable (defined as a Detail, not a Dimension) from the second query report to the first query report, I am getting a #CONTEXT error.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

To help clarify, here is some additional information.

This is what the results of my first query listed above which selects the suspect product could look like.

Results:

Case_No     Product_Name

Case001     Product001

Case002     Product002

Case003     Product003

This is what the results of my second query listed above which selects the non-suspect products could look like.

Results:

Case_No     Product_Name

Case001     Product101

Case001     Product102

Case001     Product103

Case002     Product107

Case003     Product102

Case003     Product104

Using the variables that I have defined to concatenate the non-suspect products, the report generated from the second query is formatted like this.

Case_No     Non-suspect Product Name

Case001     Product101, Product102, Product103

Case002     Product107

Case003     Product102, Product104

What I want to see when I effort to add that "Non-suspect Product Name" column from the second query report to the report generated by the first query using the merged "Case_No" as the key is this.

Case_No  /  Suspect Product Name  /  Non-suspect Product Name

Case001  /  Product001            /  Product101, Product102, Product103

Case002  /  Product002            /  Product107

Case003  /  Product003            /  Product102, Product104

Because I am doing something incorrectly, instead of displaying the concatenated non-suspect products, I get a "#CONTEXT" error in every cell in the "Non-suspect Product Name" column like this.

Case_No  /  Suspect Product Name  /  Non-suspect Product Name

Case001  /  Product001            /  #CONTEXT

Case002  /  Product002            /  #CONTEXT

Case003  /  Product003            /  #CONTEXT

Thank you for any assistance that you can provide.

Comment: Could you post the error message in order to have more information.

Comment: Try setting the "Associated Dimension" of your detail variables to your merged dimension (Case_No). Here is an example of what I mean... http://go.fusionconsultinginc.com/blog/linking-columns-in-webi-reports-without-merging-dimensions